# What is the type of string literal in C?

Tags: c, string

Is the type of a string, like `"hello, world"` a `char *` or `const char *`, as of C99? I know that in C++ it is the latter, but what about in C?

Comment: No, `std::string` is the string type in `c++`. The above are just pointer types in both languages. The "stringiness" of a buffer in `c` is decided by convention.

Comment: @StoryTeller the type of a *string literal* has nothing to do with `std::string`. In C and C++ the above are `char [N]` and `char const[N]` respectively.

Comment: @NikBougalis, he presented a misconception about `c++`, be it by a poor choice of words or his own misunderstanding. My comment is not an attempt to answer his question (which I understand perfectly, thank you).

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it because in C++ the string type is `std::string`?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: The type is `char []`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals in C are not pointers, they are arrays of `char`s. You can tell this by looking at `sizeof("hello, world")`, [which is 13](http://ideone.com/hYvYB7), because null terminator is included in the size of the literal.

C99 allows string literals to be assigned to `char *`, which is different from C++, which requires `const char *`.

Comment: well to be fair, every array of `n` length of `s size objects in C is actually a ponter to `n` consecutive `s` size data in memory.  But JoachimPileborgs' answer discusses this in more detail.

Comment: @DanFarrell Although array's name is interpreted as a pointer to its initial element in many contexts, saying that an array *is* actually a pointer would not be entirely correct. Contexts where array's name is not interpreted as a pointer to array's initial element are `sizeof` and pointer arithmetics.

Comment: ah, nice clarification.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are of type `char[N]` in C. For example, `"abc"` is an array of 4 chars (including the NUL terminator).

Answer (score 1):

The type of a string literal in C is `char[]`. This can directly be assigned to a `char*`. In C++, the type is `const char[]` as all constants are marked with `const` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

A character literal is always an array of *read-only* characters, with the array of course including the string terminator. As all arrays it of course decays to a pointer to the first element, but being *read-only* makes it a pointer to a `const`. It originated in C and was inherited by C++.

The thing is that C99 allows the weaker `char *` (without `const`) which C++ (with its stronger type system) does not allow. Some compilers may issue a warning if making a non-constant `char *` point to a string literal, but it's allowed. Trying to modify the string through the non-const `char *` of course leads to *undefined behavior*.

I don't have a copy of the C11 specification in front of me, but I don't think that C11 makes this stronger.